# How to embed an Askubuntu question or answer in a blog post?

Tags: feature-request

I have a personal blog on the Blogspot platform where I often write about Linux. There are moments when I realise that my best texts are those I've wrote here, on askubuntu. So I want to embed my own and other people's texts in my blog posts (and thus, hopefully, I won't get penalised by Google).

Besides, I really like askubuntu website and I think it deserves to be promoted a lot more (until now, I see that the main focus of media is on its bigger brother, StackOverflow).

So, my question would be the following: Is there a way to embed a question and/or answer in a blog post (no matter the platform)? I know that, for the moment, each text has its own link but that wouldn't be enough. And, if this feature isn't (yet) available, can you suggest me any workaround for this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246983/a-way-to-embed-se-posts-on-other-sites-with-interactivity-upvotes-etc

Comment: @muru Thanks for the tip! It's good to see that I'm not the only person having this idea. In fact, that user's suggestion is way more complex than mine! Still, the answers he gets aren't very enlightening for me. Everyone seems to be thrilled with this idea, but when it comes about putting it into practice, things get kinda fuzzy.

Comment: Reminds me of [StackTack](http://stackapps.com/questions/3244/stacktack-george-edison-remix-now-with-a-few-extra-features)

Comment: @jokerdino Very interesting! Thanks!

Comment: If you have a WordPress blog, there's this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/stacktack/ (**Disclaimer:** I am the author)

Comment: @NathanOsman Thanks Nathan! It's good to know and I appreciate your job, but the problem is that I don't have a WordPress blog. I have a Blogspot one and it's that very blog where I intend to embed texts from askubuntu website. Have you found a way to do this on Blogspot?

Comment: @CristianaNicolae does Blogspot allow you to embed arbitrary HTML in the article or do they use some other markup language?